# annotation processing - how to access (and modify) the contents of a field

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

I'm trying to create an annotation that will change the content of the annotated field. So far this is my annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
  String value();
}
```

And I want to use it like this

```
public class MyClass {
  @MyAnnotation("test")
  String myField;
}
```

And then I want to set the value of myField to "test" at compile time. I just don't know how I can access the annotated field from my annotation processor and if it is even possible to change its content at compile time. This is what my annotation processor looks like right now:

```
public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
  annotations.stream().flatMap(a -> roundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(a).stream())
    .forEach(e -> {
      if (!String.class.getName().equals(((VariableElement) e).asType().toString())) {
        out.printMessage(Kind.ERROR
          , "@MyAnnotation annotation can only be applied to Strings", e);
      }
      else {
        // what to do here?
      }
  });
  return true;
}
```

I am new to annotations and a little bit lost so any ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: You want to set it at _compile_ time? I don't see how you could do that. You can set it at Runtime, sure.

Comment: OK, so if it can't be done at compile time I can't really do it in the annotation processor, right? So I'll have to use reflection and also change the retention to runtime.

Comment: Well, you could manipulate the java byte code after compilation, but yes, you'd need to use reflection and change the rentention to runtime. Seems like what you're basically seeking is a preprocessor, like C and C++ have, but Java doesn't have that. In your particular query though, I'm not sure what benefit you gain over just assigning the string.

Comment: Thank you, I think this clears it up. I was thinking how easy this could be done in C++ so this is probably why I thought it has to be possible in Java somehow... And I know of course in my example I could just assign the value to the String, but my next step would have been to hopefully manipulate the annotation using compiler args, but that's useless now that I can only manipulate the field at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy using annotation processing, e.g. https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2015/09/java-annotation-processors.html

Comment: Kindly add context to any links so your Answer is self contained, meaning the answer needs to be here in the Answer itself. See ["Provide context for links"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It would be preferable if you could answer the Question in your own words here and link only as a reference.